# 3DES crypto on PHP produces different result from NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, cryptography, 3des

I'm building a checkout that need credit-card 3DES-CBC encryption, but I am getting different result on PHP and NodeJS.

PHP code:

```
    <?php

    $postfields = array(
        'CartaoNumero' => '0000000000000000',
        'CartaoMesAno' => '00/0000',
        'CartaoSeg' => '000',
        'CartaoNome' => 'Name Lastname',
        'IdentFatura' => 'companyName',
        'Valor' => '100',
        'NomeCliente' => 'Name Lastname',
        'EmailCliente' => 'test@testcompany.com',
        'CpfCliente' => preg_replace("/[.-]/", "", '111.222.333-44'),
    );
    
    $criptoKey = 'yzzqaKsC5iaZV0a2\/oexiimfYhh1yd39';
    $criptoKey = base64_decode($criptoKey);
    $criptoKey = unpack('H*', $criptoKey);
    $criptoKey = implode($criptoKey);
    
    $criptoIV = 'pO432mbTiCI=';
    $criptoIV = base64_decode($criptoIV);
    $criptoIV = unpack('H*', $criptoIV);
    $criptoIV = implode($criptoIV);
    
    
    $dataOfCard = json_encode($postfields);
    $dataOfCard = openssl_encrypt($dataOfCard, 'DES-EDE3-CBC', $criptoKey, 0, $criptoIV);
    
    echo $dataOfCard;
    
    ?>
```

> Result: bxanrc856Z+7EoICArPYFvAjFfQfmIPXyUzKjEenlMQ4QPfWbfQELs8Z3i2jWq3mn2hFZUs6PCnno2cejkY2Jtaw94Bs5E7JN4kzyn2lMH+l8LwSHdOAytw4KsxEM7MssZlcmLqk+ZaBYehZM26Ci5JcX6oBcARDxPs9EMWYzttS/xDEu2gQzaExqLZlAC9+XwWZwpVPJfgzcS5YA1PRcliYyG01G8Uj9SAFcPtJOPUttkLrrcSSuHo3SsnnhjeRyiEmR0FhgvHlnx3UCAxo4fhtH2Z6z5E5nV2RHzYU81FIP5S1Jikh4xyZAZ3Xtgm8enWl3wTg/6o=

NodeJS code:

```
    var dataOfCard ={'CartaoNumero':'0000000000000000','CartaoMesAno':'00/0000','CartaoSeg':'000','CartaoNome':'Name Lastname','IdentFatura':'companyName','Valor':'100','NomeCliente':'Name Lastname','EmailCliente':'test@testcompany.com','CpfCliente':'11122233344'};
    var secretKey = 'yzzqaKsC5iaZV0a2\/oexiimfYhh1yd39';
    var secretIV = 'pO432mbTiCI=';
    
    global.crypto = require('crypto')
    
    async function encryptCardData(dataOfCard, secretKey, secretIV) {
        try {
            const des3_key = new Buffer.from(secretKey, "base64"); 
            const des3_iv = new Buffer.from(secretIV, "base64");
            const cardString = JSON.stringify(dataOfCard);
    
            const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', des3_key, des3_iv);
            
            const encrypted = cipher.update(cardString, 'utf8', 'base64');
        
            return encrypted + cipher.final('base64');  
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Falha no momento de encrypt dos dados do cartão.", error.message);
            throw error;
        }

   }
```

> Result: TFMIANgM+pd7UOhakdfbcC2ulKLL0X6F6sXAyK3CvsnGi0f64n/sGOACQHM/rNqr/EA/QlFsTQFRBYxf6EKNg6g3Empx0FFZY77qv7oMJO3w++TW14uOaVk72uz0U9uHF2YHZGOnJ2Lm8yGang3XuT6smPraV4uw/Arzaw/qSA56ao7fQUeFhGRvIy19ta8QfMMirCRyJrnFCvK4Xmc+FxUH6qxN/svYZcz+jziPVtHryWNad9d1hO5AkgwClNI7yDaA5PxgIUQ3G+jGl1GfhI8i6Xfn1VYgfjNqW48fuoSpAz7ShNX6S1k/nyeNpF9vPZNpMEydQ94=

The NodeJS is generating the correct result. What I need to correct on PHP model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems.

1. You're calling `unpack()` and `implode()` on the key and iv for no apparent reason. Don't do that.
2. Your plaintexts are different. PHP's defaults for `json_encode()` include escaping slashes, so `"00/0000"` becomes `"00\/0000"`. You can disable this with the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` flag.